# Is there any way to get firebase auth token from google oauth2.0 token from client

Tags: java, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using Firebase 3.0 REST API and currently use only google sign in as a means of authentication. After login from android device I tried calling rest API with `idToken` obtained from below code snippet but get permission denied response:

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mUser.getToken(true)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                        }
                    }
            });
```

Is there any way to generate the id token from the client itself which can be used as access token to authenticate REST API calls?

Comment: What REST API calls do you want to authenticate, specifically? Are these calls to the RT Database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minting a Firebase Authentication token requires access to the Firebase secret and thus is inherently a server-side task.

Firebase Authentication does not expose a REST API to convert an OAuth token into a Firebase token.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Frank  for making it clear that a server is needed. Can you refer me to any documentation on minting tokens for google oauth2.0 token?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here. If you have a Google OAuth id or access token, you can exchange it for a firebase id token by calling firebase auth signInWithCredential API or whatever the equivalent is for iOS. This will resolve with a firebase current user. However if you have a Firebase id token, you cannot use it to retrieve a Google OAuth access token. Either case requires communication with the Google servers to mint the tokens.

Comment: Can I ask, what if you're making a call to your own serveless function hosting on Google Cloud Function, but you're authenticating on the client side, should you post a acccess token to the function and verify it?

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is to authenticate accesses to the realtime database with a user's credential, you have to follow the following steps:

1. Obtain Firebase Auth ID token from a signed in user (your code above exactly, just copied here for reference).

   ```
   FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   mUser.getToken(true)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                }
            }
        });
   ```
2. Make an HTTP request to one of the DB REST endpoints with such token passed as a URL parameter the "auth" parameter. Read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#auth).

Some common mistakes worth keeping an eye out for:

1. Token is expired (they last 1hr since the fetch)
2. You are sending the token to a database that belongs to a different Firebase project.
3. The signed in user does not match the restrictions specified in your security rules.